# Symfony date.timezone error on Yosemite

Tags: php, symfony

I've created a new Symfony project with

```
$ symfony new my_project
```

This is now in a folder called `/Symfony/my_project`

At this point I get this:

```
PHP Warning:  date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/src/Symfony/Installer/NewCommand.php on line 262
 ✕  Symfony 2.7.3 was successfully installed but your system doesn't meet its
     technical requirements! Fix the following issues before executing
     your Symfony application:

 * date.timezone setting must be set
   > Set the "date.timezone" setting in php.ini* (like Europe/Paris).
```

Than says

Then, you can:

```
* Change your current directory to /Users/[username]/Dropbox/private/dbx/Symfony/my_project

* Configure your application in app/config/parameters.yml file.

* Run your application:
    1. Execute the php app/console server:run command.
    2. Browse to the http://localhost:8000 URL.
```

At this point I don't know where is the php.ini file in Yosemite. I've looked around and found an answer on this but the php.ini used is not the one I edited.

Which and where is the php.ini file to edit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to modify the **real** php.ini, you can find it running `php -i | grep "php.ini"` on Terminal.

Remember that sometimes you'll find only a file called php.ini.default so you have to copy the file php.ini.default in a new php.ini file using `sudo cp php.ini.default php.ini`

Once you create the new php.ini file you have to change the permission in order to be able to modify the content:

```
sudo chmod ug+w php.ini
sudo chgrp staff php.ini
```

Now you can open the file php.ini and modify the `date.timezone` line.

**NOTE:** Remember to remove the comment if the line is commented.

If this doesn't work try to add the init function to your `AppKernel.php` file (code below), this really helped me.

```
<?php     

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    // Other methods and variables


    // Append this init function below

    public function init()
    {
        date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Paris' );
        parent::init();
    }

}
```

Comment: if(user.getFavouriteFood() == pizza || user.getFavouriteFood() == pasta){ emanuele.setMood("happy");}

;-)

Comment: Hahahaha grande! :D `if(okToBeFriend()){ findMeOnFB("Andrea ND Lombardi") }else{ noProblem() }`

Answer (score 3):

Since this is Terminal-based run and not browser based you can easily find that out. From your `Terminal`, run this:

```
php -i | grep "php.ini"
```

This will output the location of `php.ini` used. Then edit the file via any text editor (graphic or otherwise) and set the approprite time zone.

Hope this helps.